# dividend paid on FTSE100 time series data

Tags: equities, time-series, market-data, historical-data

I need dividend paid on FTSE100 for last 10 years. I want to calculate the dividend-price ratio for FTSE100 as a time series data. I would really appreciate if anybody can give me a clue about finding FTSE100 dividend data.

Edit: In particular, I am using Thomson Reuters Eikon Database. If anyone with experience on this dataset could help me it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want some data that is available for free and not a standard professional or academic database (such as CRSP or Bloomberg).

If that is the case you have some options. However, I cannot vouch for the quality of the databases as I have not used them myself.

1. If you only need the dividend yield of the FTSE you can look on [this](http://siblisresearch.com/data/ftse-all-total-return-dividend/) link for example. They have a time-series since 2000. There should be many more of such graphs online. [image]
2. If you need to construct the series by yourself, the only free datasource I found is [this](https://www.dividenddata.co.uk/dividendyield.py?market=ftse100) one. You will need to pick each security on the FTSE 100 and check one by one what are their dividends and then aggregate. Not sure how they account for entries/exits from the index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have access to Thomson Reuters Datastream (now Eikon). I want to calculate dividend-price ratio, dividend yield, dividend payout ratio in monthly basis. I also need to collect data from the different market around the world. I would really appreciate if you can tell me where and how I can get these data will help a lot.

Comment: Oh, I see. I do not have access to Eikon at the moment. I might be able to check in the office tomorrow. However, your best chance is to contact the team at Thomsom Reuters and ask. They usually are very responsive.

Comment: Thanks. I'll contact them tomorrow. if you have any information to share tomorrow, please do so.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify that you are trying to use Eikon.

Comment: that's fine. appreciate your help.